# How to deal with DateTime field when using LEFT OUTER JOIN in LinqToSql

Tags: linq-to-sql, left-join

I have 2 tables, Employee and Absence.  I want to do a left outer join so that I get all employees and any associated absences.  In LINQ2SQL I can use the following to create the LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
from e in Employees
join a in Absences on e.EmployeeID equals a.EmployeeID into ae
from x in ae.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { FullName = e.Surname + ", " + e.Forename }
```

This is what I'm looking for but I want to show any absence start dates.  I can change the select statement to

```
select new { FullName = e.Surname + ", " + e.Forename, x.StartDate }
```

but I get an error because DateTime is not nullable.
How can I show an empty string if there is no StartDate or the actual Date if there is one?  I tried using x.StartDate.ToShortDateString() but this obviously throws an error if it's null, I've also tried:

```
select new {Surname = e.Surname, StartDate = x.StartDate == null ? "" : x.StartDate }
```

but this doesn't work either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, by try using an explicit cast:

select new { StartDate = (DateTime?)x.StartDate }

Answer (score 0):

In select statement write

select new { FullName = e.Surname + ", " + e.Forename,StartDate=(DateTime?)x.StartDate }

This should work for you.